# Get the number of element or id when click?

Tags: jquery

I wonder if it's possible to get the number of a `<a>` tag when you click on it by using $this? Lets say I have a list of links and I want to get the number in the order it has inbetwen a div with a class name someLinks

```
<div class="someLinks">
 ...="#" id="1">some text or an image</a>
 ...="#" id="2">some text or an image</a>
 ...="#" id="3">some text or an image</a>
</div>
```

(sorry but I could not include a tags)

Perhaps it could be done with some code like this `$(".someLinks:eq(????` 
Or if there is some way to get the number of the ID when click on the `<a>` tag by using $this and perhaps attr?

Preciate some help! I'm new to jQuery so I want to keep the code simple. Thanks!

Comment: It seems you want `index()` (http://api.jquery.com/index/) but I'm not sure. Do you want the index of an element in the set of selected elements?

Comment: just FYI - `id` can't start with a number according to the HTML spec... You could probably use `data-id="1"` if you are passing like a mysql ID down the pipe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you mean by tag or the number of it, but if you're looking for an easy way to track a click on certain class names, you can do something like this:

```
$('.someLinks').click(function() {
    alert( $(this).attr('id') )
});
```

Comment: Hi all! I made this and it's working: var index = $(".someLinks a").index(this); Good or bad?

Answer (score 1):

You use `.index()` -function to calculate the element index based on a list- combined with `$(this)` - the link being clicked -

```
$("a").click(function(){ //when a link is clicked
    var linkList = $(".someLinks").find("a"); //Get list of links inside div
    var index = linkList.index($(this))); //Search for this in the list
    alert(index); //alert
});
```

**Online example:** http://jsfiddle.net/7kvMF/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.index(element)`](http://api.jquery.com/index) to get the position of one element in another selection, I.E:

```
var allLinks = $(".someLinks a");

allLinks.click(function(e) { 
  alert("You clicked on the "+(allLinks.index(this))+" a tag");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

You also asked about getting the elements ID:

```
allLinks.click(function(e) {
  if (this.id) alert("The A tag you clicked on was #"+this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

get the index of THIS element

```
$('.someLinks a').live('click',function(){
    alert($('.someLinks').index($(this)));

});
```